# Research based methods of introducing age appropriate physics

Tags: education

I'd like to start by saying I know this question could seem an opinion question. After browsing this site for a half hour however, what stood out was that everyone gave well researched answers. I have a minimal physics background, but am a science student, and have come to dislike the degree of opinion put forth as fact elsewhere.

Does anyone have suggestions for research based methods of introducing age appropriate physics to children. Are there researched activities? Research ages and stages?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE! What do you mean when you say "I have come to dislike the degree of opinion put forth as fact elsewhere"?

Comment: @DelCrosB  pick up a pop sci book by certain authors :) I take the OP's point as I have had to ask question for clarification on many points taken from such books.

Comment: Hi Thinking Mom. It seems a shame to close your question, but I'm afraid it's out of place here. Having said that I'm not sure where the appropriate site would be. The [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/) possibly?

Comment: It's not a parenting question really. I'm looking for ideas of what experiments I can set up for a 5 year old, to be more specific. Obviously physics is a massive subject.

Comment: Do questions about teaching and learning physics really have to be closed?

Comment: Google for sites on primary school (or pre-school) science activities. They contain lots of ideas which have been tested. eg [Education.com](http://www.education.com/activity/preschool/science/) and [HappyHooligans](http://happyhooligans.ca/20-science-activities-toddlers-preschoolers/).